# Optimization algorithm.

Tags: algorithms, word-problem

I am looking for an optimization algorithm for a program I am trying to write. To keep the question as simple as possible, I have crafted it into a story.

A carpenter receives an order for N chairs. He can only build 1 chair per day. He can also build a machine that can either build one chair per day, or can build another machine (a chair and a machine each have a one day build time). How can I optimize for the fewest amount of days needed to build N chairs? How would this be represented mathematically?

For my purposes the "day" could be as small as a fraction of a second, and N can be as large as maybe 100,000.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Someone asked a variant of this question like a month ago but with cars. They put the question on hold. My belief was to use linear programming.It works like chess, there is something called branch and bound.

Comment: Well, if you build machines until you have more $\lceil \frac{n}{2} \rceil$ or more of them then build chairs then it would be logarithmic in $n$. That's pretty fast assuming you have the space for the machines and don't mind making some extra chairs.

Comment: It seems easier to flip the problem around and figure out the most chairs you can make in a given number of days. (Hypothesis: The optimal strategy for $d$ days is to build machines for the first $d-1$ days, then make $2^{d-1}$ chairs on the last day, as @CyclotomicField suggests.) Once you establish this, the problem reduces to picking the smallest $d$ in which you can make at least $n$ chairs.